# Rich image scroll and zooming on android

Tags: android, scroll, image-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to implement image zoom and scrolling the way it is implemented in [Droid Comic Viewer](http://www.robotcomics.net/android-comic-viewer/). Is there any quick way to do that? If not, then could you please give some advices at least on implementing kinetic scrolling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It wasn't quick for us. When we implemented that part of Droid Comic Viewer we used the source code of ScrollView as reference to create a view able to handle horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Scrolling and zooming have a lot of quirks that we gradually solved, and some of them that we still have to solve.

If you're not in a hurry, we plan to release the source code later this year.

Comment: I'm attempting the same thing. Any updates on that source code?

Comment: I have an open source ImageView component that provides pinch-zoom and panning etc (similar to iPhone), and is open source:

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to implement zoom. As easy way is to set an image matrix on the ImageView:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleX, scaleX);
matrix.postTranslate(offsetX, offsetY);
mImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

If you're not familiar with touch event processing, look into [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). Using a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) can help simplify things further.

Comment: Yeah, that I've already found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection
But I still look for some good explanations on kinetic scrolling implementation on android.