# set coordinates for an imageView

Tags: android, image

i'm searching for a way to set coordinates for my imageView. i want to put other images on the coordinates.

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

My layout is like that :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rellayneuuuu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="40px" android:layout_marginLeft="40px" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by coordinates (position on the screen I guess) ? Which layout are you working with?

Comment: yes, i mean the position on the screen. it is a scrollable image. in a relative layout.

Comment: You image is bigger than the screen along X and Y axis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand you properly, but from what I get of your problem, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022380/find-position-of-imageview-relative-to-the-image-its-displaying) might just give you the answer you're looking for...

**EDIT**

I don't think that RelativeLayout is designed to hanlde this kind of behavour, maybe you should have a look at [`Framelayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) which actually is design to support superposition of views.

Comment: no, thats not what i mean. i have a image (img1) and i have another image (img2) ON img1. and i'm trying to place the img2 at a certain place on the img1, because i have to place some other images on the img1.

Comment: I've got the same problem @bebe Did u found a solution?